Why does /actuator/circuitbreakers/{name} in Spring Resilience4j return a 405 error?
I’m using Spring Boot with Resilience4j and have enabled the Actuator endpoints to monitor my circuit breakers. When I access http://localhost:8100/actuator/circuitbreakers, I get a response with the status of all circuit breakers, including accountsCB(a circuit breaker that I defined in my gateway server).
The /actuator endpoint also lists http://localhost:8100/actuator/circuitbreakers/{name} as an available endpoint, implying I should be able to get details for a specific circuit breaker by passing its name . However, when I try to access http://localhost:8100/actuator/circuitbreakers/accountsCB with a GET request, I receive a 405 Method Not Allowed error. why is that and what should I do to resolve this issue?
